# Question concerning the combination of Laravel + Vue + <script> tags

Tags: laravel, vue.js

This might be somewhat an advanced question, and I was hoping someone in here might have a solution.

I've been using Laravel + Vue.

I normally put div `#app` on the wrapper div (the one that wraps most of my application).

Then I putt Vue on this `#app` as Laravel normally does:

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

Now I started to get problems when I started using the following package:
https://github.com/albertcht/invisible-recaptcha

I have to add  `@captcha` tags to my forms, but this does generate some `<script></script>` tags inside my div `#app` (which Vue is not happy about).

```
- Templates should only be responsible for mapping the state to the UI. Avoid placing tags with side-effects in your templates, such as <script>, as they will not be parsed.
```

Does anyone have any idea how I could go about fixing this?

Or am I doing something wrong by putting Vue instance on the entire wrapper div and limiting myself from using tags? Or is this best practice?

Comment: I didn't used this package before, but tried to help you, and found a section in this package's github talking about the same problem you have: https://github.com/albertcht/invisible-recaptcha#usage-with-javascript-frameworks-like-vuejs

Comment: I'm going to look into this; I went with the first implementation that came about, namely: @captcha.

This might render my question obsolete.

Comment: Problem solved via @ApródIllés answer. Not to self, learn to read the entire documentation in case of error.

Comment: I added and answer, please accept it! :)

Comment: Accepted your answer, sorry for the delay!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [invisible-recaptcha](https://github.com/albertcht/invisible-recaptcha) 's documentation points out, you can render script tags separated from html.

Code example from documentation:

```
<-- head -->
{!! app('captcha')->renderPolyfill() !!}

<-- body -->
{!! app('captcha')->renderCaptchaHTML() !!}

<-- footer -->
{!! app('captcha')->renderFooterJS('en') !!}
```